# Trying to get value from textbox in column in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically created a table with three columns.

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>SegName</td>
  <td><input type='text' /></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to write a function that goes through each row and grabs the value in that will be in the textbox.

Javascript:

```
$("#codeSegmentBody").children().eq(x).children().eq(2).val();
```

The code brings brings up undefined when I do val(), but if I do html it'll grab the html of the textbox.

How can I get this to bring me the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="123">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="abc">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test").find(":input[type=text]").each(function(){

        alert( $(this).val() );

    }); 

});
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle that will get you there:

http://jsfiddle.net/uS8AK/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#codeSegmentBody` is the name of your table, try this:

```
$("#codeSegmentBody td input").each(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    alert(inputValue);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/45LQ7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#codeSegmentBody tr input[type='text']").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#codeSegmentBody tr").each(function() {
    alert($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the containing `<td>` not the input. Try:

```
$("#codeSegmentBody").children().eq(x).find(":text").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "";
$("#codeSegmentBody .third-column input").each(function()
{
  str += this.value;
});
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easier

```
$("table tr td input").val();
```

?

BTW. You don't have any value in this input anyway.

Comment: What if there's more than one row? ;)

Comment: BTW The user could enter something ;)